# Funky call/cc usage. How does it work?

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket, callcc

Consider following definitions. I am using Racket.

```
(define fact/k
  (lambda (n k)
    (cond
      ((zero? n) (call/cc (lambda (f) (k f))))
      (else (* n (fact/k (sub1 n) k))))))

(define five (call/cc (lambda (k) (fact/k 5 k))))
```

Now if it invoked as follows

> (five 1)

It gives out nothing. Having done that if five is invoked directly it gives 120.

$five

120

But if I retry (five 1) it fails saying 120 is not a procedure.

I understand that initially five points to the continuation captured at (zero? n) base case. But I am not sure how above behavior can be explained.

Another run with different parameter

$ (five 4)

$ five

480

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NB: You code is not allowed in the last version of #!racket without changing the language opetion. Go in Language > Choose language and uncheck "Enforce constant definitions". You'll loose some optimization wit this unchecked.

`five` is a continuation similar to `(lambda (n) (set! five (* 5 4 3 2 1 n)))` and by using two continuations you mamage to redefine `five` after one call. Evaluating `five` afterwards revieals the answer of `(* 5 4 3 2 1 1)` when the argument is `1` and  `(* 5 4 3 2 1 4)` when it's `4`.

Variables in Scheme/Racket does not have type but values have. That means a variable `five` can be a procedure/continuation first and just a number second. That is what you see happening.

**EDIT** To recap I rename a little:

```
(define fact/k
  (lambda (n k)
    (cond
      ((zero? n) (call/cc (lambda (f) (k f))))
      (else (* n (fact/k (sub1 n) k))))))

(define five (call/cc (lambda (k) (fact/k 5 k)))) ; #1
five ; ==> #<continuation>, f to be precise         #2
(five 4)                                            #3
five ; ==> 480                                      #4
```

Considering marked line #1. In `fact/k` the default case is run for n 5..1 so you can substitute the line with `(define five (call/cc (lambda (five-k) (* 5 4 3 2 1 (fact/k 0 five-k)))))`. Instead of `fact/k` returning a number it uses the continuation call with and what it passes as value is the continuation from within `fact/k` called `f`.
If you then evaluate `five` on #2 you get the `f` continuation. Calling `f` with a numeric argument becomes the last answer to the calculation that never happened since we aborted it and returned f instead.
In #3 you call `five` with 4 as argument. Continuations is time traveling so you're now back to `(define five (call/cc (lambda (five-k) (* 5 4 3 2 1 (fact/k 0 five-k)))))` where you just know that `(fact/k 0 five-k)` evaluated to `4`. What happens next is that `(* 5 4 3 2 1 4)` becomes ``` 480``and that is set to ```five`since setting the variable is done *after the calculation of it's value*.
On line #4 you verify that`five` has indeed been changed from a continuation to a value. It's value is changed to one of a totally different type. You cannot call a number.

In **DrRacket** you can hit the **debug** button and step through it. I recommend you try it out.

Comment: Think I almost got it. But why five is rebound to multiplication? Is this something to do with the fact that the start of the continuation is a return from a function? (From fact/k base case). May be I am missing some conceptual knowledge on how call/cc work to understand that.

Comment: @chamibuddhika I've updated my answer. It's because calling a continuation will be like a jump into the code. The binding of `five` is part of the continuation of both `k` and `f`